# Attempt to upgrade from wheezy results in conflict between systemd-sysv and sysvinit

Tags: debian, dist-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade an old server from Debian wheezy (yes, I'm behind the times). Can you tell me how to overcome a conflict between `systemd-sysv` and `sysvinit`?

---

I replaced mentions of `wheezy` with `jessie` in apt lists: `sed -i 's/wheezy/jessie/g' sources.list sources.list.d/*`

When I run `apt -V upgrade`, I encounter an error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/systemd-sysv_241-5_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man8/halt.8.gz', which is also in package sysvinit 2.88dsf-41+deb7u1
```

I tried to remove the existing `sysvinit` package with `dpkg -P sysvinit`, but it is not allowed because this is an essential package:

```
dpkg: error processing package sysvinit (--purge):
 this is an essential package; it should not be removed
```

(I have also tried `apt --fix-broken install`, but to no effect.)

Comment: systemd-sysv 241-5 is the buster version, not the jessie one. Upgrading from wheey to buster in one step is not supported, you have to go step by step: wheezy -> jessie -> stretch -> buster.

Answer (score 7):

I also experienced a similar problem. Solved by

```
dpkg -P --force-remove-essential sysvinit
```

Comment: very helpful.I solved using this comand.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me when I upgraded from Debian 9 Stretch into 10 Buster, where libpam-systemd requires systemd-sysv.

This worked for me:

1. Add apt sources for Buster:

   ```
    deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ buster main
    deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ buster main
    deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
    deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
   ```

and then

2. `apt-get build-dep systemd-sysv`

One of the things which happened is that libpam-systemd was removed by apt and therefore this dependency request vanished.